# Variable is reset to the value that is assigned before the loop

Tags: excel, vba

I must be overlooking something here, but after having overlooked it for an hour, it's time to get some help. This is my code:

```
For Each CurrentRow In Range(FullRange)
    PhotoIndex = 1
    For Each CurrentCell In CurrentRow
        CurrentValue = CurrentCell.Value
        If Not IsEmpty(CurrentValue) And CurrentValue <> "" Then
            FileExtensionWithPeriod = Right(CurrentValue, Len(CurrentValue) - InStrRev(CurrentValue, ".") + 1)
            If Len(FileExtensionWithPeriod) >= 4 And Len(FileExtensionWithPeriod) <= 5 Then
                MsgBox ("before: " & PhotoIndex)
                URLDownloadToFile 0, CurrentValue, FullFolderName & "\" & PhotoIndex & FileExtensionWithPeriod, 0, 0
                PhotoIndex = PhotoIndex + 1
                MsgBox ("after: " & PhotoIndex)
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next
```

For each column I get MsgBoxes that state: "before: 1" and "after: 2". Why is PhotoIndex reset to 1 in the next iteration? The rows in the range all have at least 7 columns. If I add more MsgBoxes to inspect things like CurrentValue, I can see that the code loops over these columns. Yet, PhotoIndex is reset to 1 for each column, while that assignment is outside of the loop.

FYI: the full code has `Dim` statements for all used variables.

Comment: I suspect you need: `For Each CurrentRow In Range(FullRange).Rows` and `For Each CurrentCell In CurrentRow.Cells`

Comment: Where is CurrentValue defined?

Comment: @ChristopherHamkins Good point. By removing irrelevant lines, I accidentally removed a relevant one. I have just added it in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rory's remark is the answer. Apparently the default looping through a range is column-wise, not row-wise. I am an experienced programmer, but VBA is something that I do rarely (last time was about 15 years ago, I think).

So, changing

```
For Each CurrentRow In Range(FullRange)

For Each CurrentCell In CurrentRow
```

into

```
For Each CurrentRow In Range(FullRange).Rows

For Each CurrentCell In CurrentRow.Cells
```

solves the problem.